# How to export multiple packages using setup.py

Tags: python

I want to export a package of a python program that contents the main code (memoryPuzzle folder) and a sprite folder

```
    C:.
    │   .gitignore
    │   LICENSE
    │   README.md
    │
    ├───MemoryPuzzle-1.0
    │   │   setup.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   ├───dist
    │   │       MemoryPuzzle-1.0.tar.gz
    │   │
    │   ├───doc
    │   │       updates.md
    │   │
    │   ├───memoryPuzzle
    │   │       main.py
    │   │
    │   ├───MemoryPuzzle.egg-info
    │   │       dependency_links.txt
    │   │       PKG-INFO
    │   │       SOURCES.txt
    │   │       top_level.txt
    │   │
    │   └───sprites
    │           greatball.png
    │           heavyball.png
    │           masterball.png
    │           moonball.png
    │           pokeball.png
    │           premierball.png
    │           safariball.png
    │           ultraball.png
    │
    └───__pycache__
            main.cpython-37.pyc
```

I try to export this by using the setuptools library:

```
    from setuptools import setup

    setup (

        name = "MemoryPuzzle",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "A memory puzzle build on python",
        author = "Adri-md-1208", 
        author_email = "a.morales.2019@alumnos.urjc.es",
        url = "https://github.com/Adri-md-1208/Memory-puzzle",
        packages = [
                    "memoryPuzzle",
                    "sprites"
                    ],
        license = "GPLv3",

    )
```

Then I try to make the package in the command shell by using python setup.py sdist. Python creates a package where is included the memoryPuzzle folder, but not the sprites folder.
And when I try to import the package from pip (pip install memoryPuzzle) the shell output the following error: `error: package directory 'sprites' does not exist`

Comment: You tried and what happened? Please explain the issue, your approach and what you expected to happen. For more information [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Instead of adding the relevant information here, you should add it to the main question by editing it.